# Setting z-index correctly in slider css

Tags: css, html

The links of my **slider**, just the firts works, the rest overwrites.

I have three links, but only one works.

I believe it is a problem with **z-index**. However I can not make it work.

**CSS** details follow the link on codepen.

```
<div class="gallery autoplay items-3" style="position: absolute; top: 110px;">

    <figure class="item">
   <img src="http://comercialbv.com.br/slide/image/banner-kit-utilidades.jpg" alt="Olha só o presente que você vai dar no Dia dos Pais!"  usemap="#kitchurrasco" id="kitchurrasco">
    </figure>

    <figure class="item">
<img src="http://comercialbv.com.br/slide/image/banner-rechauds.jpg" alt="Rechaud Banho Maria GN 1/2 65mm - F433-02" usemap="#rechaud" id="rechaud">
    </figure>

    <figure class="item">
<img src="http://comercialbv.com.br/slide/image/banner-refrigerador.jpg" alt="Promoção Exclusiva! Refrigerador Expositor 360 Litros LG-360" usemap="#refrigerator" id="refrigerator">

<map name="kitchurrasco" id="kitchurrasco">
<area  alt="Kit p/ Churrasco Aço Inox - Mundial" href="http://yahoo.com" shape="rect" coords="0,0,847,300" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area shape="rect" coords="845,298,847,300" alt="Kit p/ Churrasco Aço Inox - Mundial" style="outline:none;" title="Kit p/ Churrasco Aço Inox - Mundial" href="http://yahoo.com" />
</map>   

<map name="rechaud" id="rechaud">
<area  alt="Rechaud Banho Maria Aço Inox GN 1/2 65mm 9 Litros" title="Rechaud Banho Maria Aço Inox GN 1/2 65mm 9 Litros" href="http://www.google.com" shape="rect" coords="0,0,847,300" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area shape="rect" coords="845,298,847,300" alt="Rechaud Banho Maria Aço Inox GN 1/2 65mm 9 Litros" style="outline:none;" title="Rechaud Banho Maria Aço Inox GN 1/2 65mm 9 Litros" href="http://www.google.com" />
</map>


<map name="refrigerator" id="refrigerator">
<area  alt="Promoção Exclusiva! Refrigerador Expositor 360 Litros LG-360" href="http://www.bing.com" shape="rect" coords="0,0,847,300" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area shape="rect" coords="845,298,847,300" alt="Promoção Exclusiva! Refrigerador Expositor 360 Litros LG-360" style="outline:none;" title="Promoção Exclusiva! Refrigerador Expositor 360 Litros LG-360" href="http:/www.bing.com" />
</map>
      </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbzopM

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just make sure the 100% has a z-index of 1 -

```
@keyframes controlAnimation-2 {
    0% {
        color: #ccc;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
        z-index: 7;
    }

    14.3%,
    50% {
        color: white;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        z-index: 7;
    }

    64.3%,
    100% {
        color: #ccc;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer-me, but i dont understand. All @keyframes or just the controlAnimation-2? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbzopM

Comment: No, all of them need to have a z-index: 1 at 100% - it's basically saying "when this image is 100%, put it on top of all the other images, and make it clickable". The z-index is a layering system, so if you had a stack of papers, z-index: 1 would be the top paper, and you can only touch or interact with the top paper! Even if the opacity of that top paper is 0, it's still on top of the stack - hope that makes a little sense.

Comment: I followed his instructions, i understand, but can not make it work.  Can you check in codepen? http://codepen.io/4ntr4xvini/pen/YXBXmb